# Stress–energy pseudotensor of gravitation field for Dark energy

Tags: general-relativity, energy-conservation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, dark-energy

Suppose we have Einstein equation for *Universe free of matter* in form
\begin{equation}
 G_{ik} = \chi T_{ik},
\end{equation}
where the cosmological constant $\Lambda$  is transferred to the RHS of equation and written in the form of stress–energy tensor of Dark Energy:

\begin{equation}\label{1}
 T_{ik} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \rho & 0    & 0 & 0    \\
  0    & \rho & 0 & 0    \\
  0    & 0    & \rho & 0 \\
  0    & 0    & 0 & \rho
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Also, we can introduce the [stress–energy pseudotensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy%E2%80%93momentum_pseudotensor) of gravitation field in form of Landau-Lifshitz $t^{ik}$ and figure out:
\begin{equation}\label{2}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x^k} (-g) (T^{ik} + t^{ik}) = 0.
\end{equation}

Is it possible to find an expression for $t^{ik}$ pseudotensor, not counting it by the general formula from Landau-Lifshitz?

Comment: Dark energy is generally thought to be nothing more than a nonzero cosmological constant.  The signature of its stress-energy tensor should be +--- or -+++ depending on your favorite convention.

Comment: @Bert Barrois stress-energy tensor is T =(rho,-p,-p,-p), but p = - rho

Comment: @Sergio: $\mathrm{diag}(\rho, - p ,-p,-p)$ is the structure of $T^i_j$.

Comment: @A.V.S. this is exactly what I meant